# VueJS : relative resources doesn't work behind reverse proxy

Tags: vue.js, reverse-proxy, traefik

## Intro

I serve all types of containers (docker) behind a reverse proxy (traefik 2.0), like backend apps (nodejs) or frontend apps (vuejs).
Actually, I am trying to serve a VueJS behind a path like `https://localhost/my-app`.

## What I expect

- Traefik redirecting `/my-app` to my vuejs container
- VueJS app working clean.
- VueJS app loads resources with relative paths like `<link href=css/app.css>`.

## What I have instead

- VueJS app not working because is not getting resources properly.
- I am getting only index.html (root page of VueJS) behind `https://localhost/my-app`
- My browser is trying to get relative resources on `https://localhost/css/app.css` instead of `https://localhost/my-app/css/app.css`
  Have you an idea how to serve VueJS with relative resources behind my `/my-app` redirection

## Configuration files

See configuration files below.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  vuejs:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: my-vuejs-app:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.rule=PathPrefix(`/my-app`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.path-strip.stripprefixregex.regex=^/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.middlewares=path-strip@docker"
```

### vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './'
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bruno MC , I did not manage to make it work without changing the publicPath to /my-app, can you please share your full config .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a middleware that adds a `/` at the end of the request. This way, the relative resources are loaded as expected.

**Example:** *(labels for Traefik in my Docker service)*

```yaml
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.tls=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.rule=PathPrefix(`/my-app`)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^(https|http)://([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$$"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=$${1}://$${2}/$${3}/"
- "traefik.http.routers.my-app-router.middlewares=test-redirectregex@docker,path-strip@file"
```

Comment: This config will throw an error because there middleware path-strip@file does not exist.